# In Google Sheets, how can I fit the data to the cell?

Tags: google-sheets

In some cells on my sheet the data fits the cell.  On some rows there is a lot of extra space after the data in each cell.  I have tried deleting after at the end of the data, but it does not help.

How do I size the cell to fit the data?

Comment: Can you provide more info, perhaps a link to the doc, or a link to an example spreadsheet? It's hard to tell what you mean just from the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the cursor on the column divider at the top and drag it to move the righthand border of the cells in the column.

before:

[image: Google Column before]

after:

[image: Google Column after]